# Find element in XML file by CDATA attribute using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have an XML file and I need to parse it and get only one product by its SKU.

Every product attribute contains text in a CDATA block.

The XML file is:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>
            <![CDATA[
                name1
            ]]>
        </name>
        <price>
            <![CDATA[
                Price1
            ]]>
        </price>
        <SKU>
            <![CDATA[ 
                p-1 
            ]]>
        </SKU>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>
            <![CDATA[
                name2
            ]]>
        </name>
        <price>
            <![CDATA[
                Price2
            ]]>
        </price>
        <SKU>
            <![CDATA[ 
                p-2 
            ]]>
        </SKU>
    </product>
   ...
</products>
```

How can I get a product in hash format

```
{:name => 'name2', :price => 'price2', :sku => 'p-2'}
```

if I have only `@sku='p-2'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about CDATA, Nokogiri can deal with it. You can simply iterate on all `<product>` and, for each of them, on its children (in the code below I limited the children only to that three of them).

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
out = []
doc.xpath('//products/product').each do |product|
  h = {}
  product.xpath('name | price | SKU').each do |child|
    h["#{child.name}"] = child.text.strip
  end
  out << h
end
```

The result is an array of hashes:

```
[{"name"=>"name1", "price"=>"Price1", "SKU"=>"p-1"},
 {"name"=>"name2", "price"=>"Price2", "SKU"=>"p-2"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I was need only one record, so I use your code with
`if product.xpath('SKU').text == @sku`